# Load few csv files from the same folder

Tags: r, csv

I'd like to load to R like 30-40 csv files which I have in the same folder. There is nothing more, just those files.

I want to import them as a different data.frames, let's name them:
tbl1
tbl2
tbl3
tbl4

etc.

Can I load all of them at once or should I do it one bye one ?

It would be nice if script could load all of csv files in a folder, not a selected number, because in future I may have a different number of csv files.

Comment: the answers below are good. I also feel like this *must* have been answered on SO a few times already, but don't have time to search for duplicates at the moment ... note that several of the answers below give you the results stored as a list rather than as separate variables, which in the long run is a more idiomatic and therefore probably a better way to deal with a group of objects ...

Answer (score 1):

This Should Work

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.delim)
```

Comment: Note, that `pattern` expects a regular expression. `*.csv` works for some reason, but it should be either `pattern = ".*?\\.csv"` or simply `pattern = "csv$"`. Oh and depending on the task `read.csv2` might be the better choice than `read.delim`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try it:

```
tbl = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(tbl)) assign(tbl[i], read.csv(tbl[i]))
```

The name of the files you load will be exactly the same.